# Remotefunction not working

Tags: grails, groovy, hql, grails-orm

Below is my Pgtyp.groovy (domain class):

```
package marchmock2

class Pgtyp {
   Date date_hour
   String mv
   String pagetype
   Integer visits
   Integer visits_ly
   Integer visits_lw
   String time_period
   String platform
   String device
   String browser

   static mapping = {
      table "pgtyp"
      version false 
      date_hour column: "date_hour"
      mv column: "mv"
      pagetype column: "pagetype"
      visits column: "visits"
      visits_ly column:"visits_ly"
      visits_lw column:"visits_lw"
      time_period column:"time_period"
      platform column:"platform"
      device column:"device"
      browser column:"browser"
   }       

   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

This is how my controller looks like:

```
package marchmock2
import grails.converters.*
import groovy.sql.Sql 

class PgtypController {

   def ajaxGetMv = {
      def pgtyp = Pgtyp.get(params.id)
      render pgtyp as JSON
   }

   def index() { 
   }
}
```

And finally, this is my index.gsp:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <g:javascript src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>
      <g:javascript src="prototype.js"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'SEO', 'SEM','DISPLAYADS']" name="mv" onchange="${remoteFunction(
        controller:'Pgtyp', 
        action:'ajaxGetMv', 
        params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)',
        onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}"></g:select>
      </form>
      <g:javascript>
         function printpgtyp(data) {
            console.log(data)
         }
      </g:javascript>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I run my app, I get a dropdown and on selecting any option from it I get an error saying:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/marchmock2/pgtyp/ajaxGetMv 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What do I do with it? Is there any error in the way I'm writing it or have I misunderstood anything? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
|
2014-07-04 16:37:23,149 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR [/marchmock2].[gsp]  - Servlet.service() for servlet   [gsp] in context with path [/marchmock2] threw exception
Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the       following have not been rendered: [defer]
Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

**UPDATE2**

Following an answer on stackoverflow, I changed  to  and the error mentioned in first **UPDATE** is gone. However, when I select 'SEO' from the dropdown, I get the following error

```
TypeMismatchException occurred when processing request: [POST] /marchmock2/pgtyp/ajaxGetMv - parameters:
id: SEO
Provided id of the wrong type for class marchmock2.Pgtyp. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class     java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Provided id of the wrong type for class marchmock2.Pgtyp. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class      java.lang.String
```

Comment: any exceptions in log?

Comment: also why prototype and jquery - surely thats gotta be causing you some grief...

Comment: @injecteer check the update in the question

Comment: @vahid I didn't have then earlier but I was getting some errors which I googled and then ended up in adding those. the app was not running without them

Comment: @injecteer-- Is there some kind of type- mismatch in the parameters.params.id is supposed to be a string.

Comment: that error relates to you calling g tags but not having properly set up the page... try adding the main.gsp reference to the page.. and add relevant require statement for jquery to your main.gsp or this page...

Comment: try enabling web console on firefox/chrome and monitor what url + params are being passed to calling url --- also try going to http://localhost:8080/yourapp/pgType/ajaxGetMv?id=something  does this work ?

Comment: Please, check the second update in the question

Comment: Id is a long on your domain class, you're passing a string

Comment: I tried this. http://localhost:8080/marchmock2/pgtyp/ajaxGetMv/id=SEO and I get the same error as in update2 i.e. Provided id of the wrong type for class marchmock2.Pgtyp. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @tim_yates I don't have anything called id in my domain class and mv is a string.There is nothing of the kind 'long' in my domain class

Comment: Grails adds an id field for you. Try `Pgtyp.findByMv( params.id )`

Comment: Parse the String to a Long, if you don't get a NumberFormatException do a Pgtyp.get(ID), otherwise you'll have to look it up usind findBy or findAllBy

Comment: @tim_yates  Done that, another error 'Unknown column 'this_.id' in 'field list' '

Comment: @tim_yates error sorted ..added an auto-increment not null primary key column called id.However, my table size is huge. I actually can't afford adding this column.Is there any work- around?